# Is it possible to use both of auth and auth:api middlewares on the same controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I got the task to implement API for mobile using Laravel Passport (for OAUTH2 support). I want to reuse the same Controller methods (some of them) that I use on the website. I have tried doing this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

But that doesn't work (why?). Do I just have to create new controllers for the api? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file you can specify multiple middleware's by doing.

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'auth'])->group(function() {
    //my routes
});
```

But it seems like for your use, you could just use `auth:api` in your api routes file and `auth` in your web routes file.

Additionally if you'd like to middleware the entire controller without grouping via routes you can use middleware groups.

In your Http `Kernel.php` add a new index to the array `$middlewareGroups`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],

    'both' => [
        'auth:api',
        'auth'
    ],
];
```

Then in your controller you should be able to do:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('both');
}
```

Additionally you can exclude methods within the controller from the middleware group.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('both', ['except' => [ 'methodOne', 'methodTwo' ]]);
}
```

Comment: I want to do that in my constructors, is that possible? I tried `$this->middleware(['auth', 'auth:api]);` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Having it in your controller means that the user has to be logged into your website AND have an access token at the same time (something that will break your mobile API). Luminosity's answer about just having different sets of routes (ie web and api) and applied the middleware at that level makes the most sense and allows you reuse the controller without all that extra code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 2 different Auth guards checking for a user you can do that with the `auth` middleware. It takes a unspecified number of parameters:

```
auth:web,api
```

That will check each guard for a user until one is returned then use that as the current guard for the request.

What you have are 2 different middleware being ran in the stack. Since only one of them will actually pass you are always 'unauthenticated' with your setup. (unless you have a session and are passing a token for some odd reason).

[SO - Laravel two diffrent middleware authentication from auth middleware only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115674/laravel-two-diffrent-middleware-authentication-from-auth-middleware-only/52117526#52117526)

[SO - Laravel multi auth protecting route multple middleware not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818128/laravel-multi-auth-protecting-route-multple-middleware-not-working/51818399#51818399)